# How do I corrupt an mdb intentionally for test purposes

Tags: ms-access

I'm creating a process to check for corrupt tables in an MDB on server.  There's no code, just tables.
I would like to corrupt an mdb intentionally for testing.  Has anyone ever done this?

Comment: Open the file in a text editor and add or delete arbitrary characters/lines.

Comment: Alternately, you could simply open the .mdb file in Access, then "End Task" the Access task from Windows Task Manager.  That should probably do the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How to launch the Detect and Repair Tool you may see below

1. Start MS Access 2007.
2. Click the MS Access button and click the PowerPoint options button.
3. Select the Resource Tab.
4. Click the Diagnose button.

But also you can get more resources to solve problem .mdb file

http://www.itninja.com/question/copying-1-2-gb-mdb-from-pc-to-network

Ultimate solution you may use only if previous methods didn't work, that denotes your .mdb corruption is severe, see and try it http://www.mdb.openfiletool.com/ MDB Open File Tool